# How to write a program that displays numeric limits of a data type in a table

Tags: c++

I'm currently learning how to program in C++ and one of the practical examples is to write a program showing the data types numeric limit in a table. Currently writing in repl.it before pasting to .txt and compiling using makefile. There are no resources or similar examples I could find explaining how to do this, nor have I fully grasped enough to ID the correct keywords to use.

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9Qqp.jpg)

Attempt:

```
#include <limits>

void main()
{
number = sizeor(int)
unsign = sizeor(unsigned int)
long = sizeor(long)
longlong = sizeor(long_long)
unsignedchar = sizeor(unsigned char)
float = sizeor(float)
double = sizeor(double)
char = sizeor(char)

cout<<numeric_limits<int>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<int>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<int>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<double>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<double>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<long>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<long>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<long>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<longlong>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<longlong>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<longlong>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<unsignedchar>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<unsignedchar>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<unsignedchar>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<float>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<float>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<float>::epsilon();

cout<<numeric_limits<char>::min();
cout<<numeric_limits<char>::max();
cout<<numeric_limits<char>::epsilon();
}
```

Except this prints

```
main.cpp:5:2: error: expected function body after function declarator
    number = sizeor(int)
    ^
main.cpp:15:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<int>::max();
    ^
main.cpp:15:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<int>::max();
        ^
main.cpp:16:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<int>::epsilon();
    ^
main.cpp:16:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<int>::epsilon();
        ^
main.cpp:18:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::min();
    ^
main.cpp:18:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::min();
        ^
main.cpp:19:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::max();
    ^
main.cpp:19:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::max();
        ^
main.cpp:20:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
    ^
main.cpp:20:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<double>::epsilon();
        ^
main.cpp:22:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::min();
    ^
main.cpp:22:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::min();
        ^
main.cpp:23:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::max();
    ^
main.cpp:23:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::max();
        ^
main.cpp:24:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::epsilon();
    ^
main.cpp:24:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<unsign>::epsilon();
        ^
main.cpp:26:2: error: unknown type name 'cout'
    cout<<numeric_limits<long>::min();
    ^
main.cpp:26:6: error: expected unqualified-id
    cout<<numeric_limits<long>::min();
```

What is the correct method to acquire the desired result and where/what are the deficiencies in my attempt that I need to correct?

Comment: Pay *extremely* close attention to every character. `sizeor` and `sizeof` might look similar, but they're not the same.

Comment: Hint: `cout` isn't a thing. `std::cout` is.

Comment: Tip: Instead of typing all of this code in and then mashing the compile button, start with the most minimal program, *ensure it compiles*, and build incrementally from there. Compile *frequently*. Stop adding more code the instant you have a compile problem, fix that issue before making things worse.

Comment: `number` etc are not declared and missing `;` `long = sizeor(long)` tries to use a keyword are a variable name.  Please refer to the [list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/a/388282)

Comment: Why have you got all of those 'sizeor' statements at the start of your code anyway?  You don't use them.  Also, some of the types in your 'numeric_limits' statements are incorrect, so you should review those.

Comment: `sizeof` gives you a number of bytes. The number of _bits_ is 8 times larger.

Comment: Building on what tadman wrote, your first error is on the first line in your `main` function. Try reducing your program to `#include <limits>
void main()
{
number = sizeor(int)
}` and focusing on what is preventing that much from compiling. (A [mre] is a powerful debugging tool; it doesn't matter that there is no useful functionality yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're quite a lot of errors/typos within your code.

1. `void main()` will return a `'::main' must return 'int'` error, the correct syntax is `int main()`.
2. `number =`  (IMO is Pythonic syntax) should be `int number =` , as in C++, the correct format for declaring variables is `type variable_name = value;`. More info [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cpp/cpp_variables.asp#:%7E:text=Declaring%20(Creating)%20Variables&text=type%20variable%20%3D%20value%3B,assign%20values%20to%20the%20variable.).
3. Variables declarations should all end with `;`, or the program will return a `error: expected ',' or ';' before 'int'`.
4. A keyword such as `int` or `char` mustn't be used as a variable name.
5. `sizeor()` is not a valid operator, it's `sizeof()` as specified clearly in your question.
6. `cout`  and `numeric_limits<int>::min()` is invalid, it should be `std::cout` and `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()`, or you can use `using namespace std;` instead. Also, when using `cout`, `#include <iostream>` must be used.
7. Some of the type you used is invalid, such as `long_long` should be `long long`, `unsign` should be `unsigned int` and `unsignedchar` should be `unsigned char`.

I include a little snippet of your code which have been modified here (you can build and fill in the rest from this):

```
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int number = sizeof(int);
    int unsign = sizeof(unsigned int);
    int long_ = sizeof(long);
    int longlong = sizeof(long long);
    int unsignedchar = sizeof(unsigned char);
    int float_ = sizeof(float);
    int double_ = sizeof(double);
    int char_ = sizeof(char);

    std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<int>::min() << "\n";
    std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::min() << "\n";
    std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<long long>::min() << "\n";
    std::cout<<std::numeric_limits<float>::min() << "\n";
}
```

Result:

```
-2147483648
 
-9223372036854775808
1.17549e-38
```

- It should also be noticed that `sizeof()` actually "Yields the size in bytes of the object representation of `type`", not bits. As @Nathan Pierson mentioned, the number of bits is **8** times more than the number of bytes.

P.S: As @tadman mentioned above:

> Instead of typing all of this code in and then mashing the compile
> button, start with the most minimal program, ensure it compiles, and
> build incrementally from there. Compile frequently. Stop adding more
> code the instant you have a compile problem, fix that issue before
> making things worse.

And @JaMiT :

> Building on what tadman wrote, your first error is on the first line
> in your main function. Try reducing your program to `#include <limits> void main() { number = sizeor(int) }` and focusing on what is
> preventing that much from compiling. (A [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
> is a powerful debugging tool; it doesn't matter that there is no
> useful functionality yet.)

IMO, you're not really familiar with C++ syntaxes, maybe you should try some simpler program first to get the hang of it. The [list of books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) @Richard Critten provided is very useful for beginners.

More info:

`std::numeric_limits` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits

`sizeof()` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof

`std::cout` : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/cout

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is an operator and keyword in c++, and it calculates the bytes of data type or variables during the complying time. remember that `sizeof` is an operator, not a function.